# 2 класса для ссылок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть файл `style.css`, который отвечает за стили сайта, в нем прописаны - `a, a:active, a:hover`, определяющие стили ссылок.
Захотелось часть ссылок на сайте сделать немного отличающимися от них. Первое что пришло в голову заключить ссылки в тег `<p>`, ссылающийся на классы `new2 a`, `new2 a:active`, `new2 a:hover` :

```
<p class="new2">
  <a ...>css</a>
</p>
```

Результата естественно нет, т.к. ссылка будет все равно с классом `a, a:active, a:hover`. Естественно можно переправить ссылки на `new1 a, new1 a:active, new1 a:hover`, тогда класс `new2` будет работать.

Есть ли другой способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать стили для нужных ссылок, например для всех:

```
a{color: blue;}
```

Для некоторых:

```
a.some{color: green !important;}
```

Получиться:

```
<a>Синяя</a>
<a class="some">Зеленая</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p.new2 a {}
p.new2 a:active {}
p.new2 a:hover {}
```

Comment: ок, понял. спасибо